# Azure function does not accept XML, v4 net6.0

Tags: c#, xml, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I am trying to create an azure function that will receive XML files and process them accordingly. I managed to achieve this on my local environment and everything works as intended but when I deployed it to Azure and testing, it comes back with the following 500 internal server error:

- Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Is the exact same xml that works on the local environment, I checked it on the online validators and on visual studio, there is no problem with the xml. Hoovering over the text brings:

- Only content-type of application/json is accepted.

I have tried different approaches in code to go around reading the string but with no success:

```
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
                //string msg = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                XmlDocument xmlDocumnet = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocumnet.LoadXml(await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync());
```

and

```
string msg = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                    writer.Write(msg);
                    writer.Flush();
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    xmlDocumnet.Load(stream);
                }
```

I tried to add a header to specify content-type : text/xml but it comes back with a 500:

- Only content-type of application/json is accepted.

What would be the best approach in this case? I was thinking to create an intermediary storage which I then would load the file in the function without passing it into the body but that would increase the processing time.

Comment: I don't see any code where you pass it to Azure, nor where the Azure function accepts the request, please show that code

Comment: Updated, as requested...nothing special on the function, standard format

Comment: Can we have the client side code also? Looks like you are reading the stream twice, you should just do `xmlDocumnet.LoadXml(req.Body);` and forget the `StreamReader` and `MemoryStream`

Comment: It is not reading it twice, the string declared as msg is used for the next piece of code that I attached. It was commented and I accidentally deleted the comment when I updated the question. The client side has nothing to do with the error because I am deploying it using vs 2022 and testing this using Azure code+test.

Comment: have you logged req.Body?

Comment: Yes, when I run it locally it logs the actual xml with no other elements:  C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2022-09-09T15:07:14.955Z] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><email><to>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</to></email>

Comment: So what happens if you do `xmlDocumnet.LoadXml(req.Body);` (and no other reading of the stream as you cannot read it twice)

Comment: It works on the local machine as intended but once I deploy it to azure it bring the errors I mentioned above.

Comment: You have to send the header `Content-Type: text/xml` when making the call to an actual Azure function

Comment: I have tried that already, doesn’t work